# How can I force a Bootstrap table to resize wider than its parent container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a spreadsheet-like application using a Bootstrap table. A user can toggle column visibility, add/delete columns, resize, etc.

I need the table to be able to scroll horizontally when a user chooses to resize a column, as well as add new ones, but Bootstrap tries to fit the table into the parent container. A basic Bootstrap table:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <table id="grid" class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>One</th>
        <th>Two</th>
        <th>Three</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
      <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

And the code to resize (credit to user686605 on SO):

```
$(function() {
 var pressed = false;
 var start = undefined;
 var startX, startWidth;

$("#grid").on('mousedown', 'th', function(e) {
    start = $(this);
    pressed = true;
    startX = e.pageX;
    startWidth = $(start).width();
    $(start).addClass("resizing");
  });

  $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    if ( pressed ) {
      $(start).width(startWidth+(e.pageX-startX));
    }
  });

  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    if ( pressed ) {
      pressed = false;
    }
  });
});
```

Demo in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xc0v6gkk/1/

On resizing, you can see the table headers that are not being resized becoming smaller to fit the increasing width of the resized column. Is there a way that I can force those columns to stay the same width, and force the table to grow wider than its parent, revealing a horizontal scrollbar in the process?

When you add enough columns, the table will exceed the boundaries of its parent, but resizing is no longer possible.

I have tried to check widths on resize and increase the div when the table reaches a certain width, but you still aren't able to keep dragging the column further horizontally as the div's width increases:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  if (pressed) {
    $(start).width(startWidth + (e.pageX - startX));

    var docWidth = $('.wrapper').width(),
      gridWidth = $('#grid').width();

    if (docWidth - gridWidth == 15) {
      $('.wrapper').width(docWidth + 100);
    }
  }
});
```

EDIT

I think it's important for me to know why the resizing stops working when the table starts to overflow. The resizing process is kind of finicky, but it's something that can be tweaked. I just can't understand why the resizing stops working when the table overflows.

Comment: are you looking for this ? https://jsfiddle.net/xc0v6gkk/2/

Comment: Don't use the boostrap table, use instead a class that you can put a css like: overflow-x : scroll

Comment: @Full.C It is definitely something that I considered. However, the application has various modules which all use Bootstrap tables. I would have to style the non-bootstrap table to look similar, and my css skills just aren't good enough for something like that. That's why I am looking for a solution that uses the Bootstrap table first.

Comment: @IsmailFarooq Thank you for the comment. Can you possibly submit an answer that explains why this works? I see that you assign fixed widths to all th and tds?

Answer (score 0):

You can force to the table to resize to the desired width every time a new column is added. you can multiply the column width the number of additional columns and add that to the starting width.

```
var newCols = 0,
    width = 160,
    tableWidth = 400;

$('#add-col').on('click', function(e) {
    newCols++
    $('#grid').width(tableWidth + (width * newCols));
    $('thead tr').append('<th>Another</th>');
    $('tbody tr').append('<td>More</td>');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xc0v6gkk/13/

You'll need to play with the settings to get this spot on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is fine if you disregard the resizing capabilities of the grid. As soon as the amount of columns increase enough so that the div starts to overflow, resizing no longer works.

Comment: I see, I will have think about this, tricky as that is what caused the resizing.

Comment: Min width not works with display table cell or row property

Comment: I have an idea how to get this to work, it involves giving the table a width equal to the desired width of a column * No. of columns. You will need to use javascript to update the table width on button click. This should ensure that the widths remain the same as they should fill the table width.